# Problems with modeling AR(1) with three different techniques in R: 1. the formula 2.for-loop 3.arima.sim

Tags: r, for-loop, formula, modeling, autoregressive-models

(reproducible example added)
I tried to model Y<sub>t</sub>=0.6Y<sub>t-1</sub>+V<sub>t</sub> (V<sub>t</sub> ~ N(0,1)) AR(1) with three different techniques.

**1.** The formula Y<sub>t</sub> =ρ<sup>t</sup>[y<sub>1</sub>/ρ + ∑<sub>j=2 to t</sub> (α+V<sub>j</sub>)/ρ<sup>j</sup>] of Y<sub>t</sub>=α+ρY<sub>t-1</sub>+V<sub>t</sub> obtained via back substitution and using cumulative sum.

**2.** The classical `for` loop

**3.** `arima.sim` simulation.

While I expect to get more or less the same things, interesting and unexpected things happened:

```
N <- 1388; ro <- 0.6; a <- 0
set.seed(1)
v <- ts(rnorm(N,0,1))

# Formula technique
y1 <- ts(rep(0,N))  # y[1]:=0 defined
y1[-1] <- ro^(2:N) * (y1[1]/ro + cumsum((a+v[-1]) / ro^(2:N)))

# The classical "for" loop
y2 <- ts(rep(0,N))  # y2[1]:=0 defined    
for (t in 2:N){  y2[t] <- a + ro*y2[t-1]+v[t] }

# arima.sim simulation 
set.seed(1) 
y3 <- arima.sim(model=list(ar=0.6), n=1388, mean=0, sd=sqrt(1)) 
# change n in arima.sim accordingly such that n=N simultaneously with the N definition above


c(mean(y1),sd(y1))
c(mean(y2),sd(y2))
c(mean(y3),sd(y3))
```

N=1388 (and n=1388) gives:

```
[1] -0.03713488  1.26102077
[1] -0.03713488  1.26102077
[1] -0.01048798  1.28445899
```

N=1389 (and n=1389) gives:

```
[1] Inf NaN
[1] -0.03661779  1.26071373
[1] -0.01048798  1.28445899
```

The standard deviation values are just as expected:
StdDev(Y<sub>t</sub>)=sqrt[sd(v)<sup>2</sup>/(1-ρ<sup>2</sup>)]

```
sqrt(sd(v)^2/(1-(0.6)^2)) # 1.284229
```

Strangenesses appear for the formula technique:

`c(mean(y1),sd(y1))` is defined for N<=1388
`c(mean(y1),sd(y1))` is (Inf, NaN) for N=1389 and N=1390
`c(mean(y1),sd(y1))` is (NaN, NA) for N>=1391.

**Question:**
**1.** Why do the formula technique fail for N>=1989?
(though we have a stationary series with ρ=0.6)

**2.** Why do we get `c(mean(y1),sd(y1))#(Inf, NaN)` for N=1389 and N=1390 and
`c(mean(y1),sd(y1))#(NaN, NA)` for N>=1391?

Comment: Perfect question for stats.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Welcome to floating point numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `N <- 1389; ro <- 0.6; a <- 0` the last element of `cumsum((a+v[-1]) / ro^(2:N))` is larger than the maximally representable number on your PC i.e. your `.Machine$double.xmax`. (I am assuming here it is maximally `1.797693e+308`. Thus it is represented as `Inf`. This causes the last element of y1 to become an `Inf` as well as any legal arithmetic operation on `Inf` and a numeric yields `Inf`. `sd` of a vector conatining an `Inf` is a `NaN`:

```
N <- 1389; ro <- 0.6; a <- 0
set.seed(1)
v <- ts(rnorm(N,0,1))

# Formula technique
y1 <- ts(rep(0,N))  # y[1]:=0 defined
y1[-1] <- ro^(2:N) * (y1[1]/ro + cumsum((a+v[-1]) / ro^(2:N)))

tail((a+v[-1]) / ro^(2:N))
#[1] -8.183997e+306  1.049540e+307 -1.581977e+306 -3.189985e+307 -7.577105e+307
#[6]            Inf
tail(cumsum((a+v[-1]) / ro^(2:N)))
#[1] -1.814422e+307 -7.648815e+306 -9.230793e+306 -4.113064e+307 -1.169017e+308
#[6]            Inf
tail(y1)
#[1] -1.6598499 -0.4198324 -0.3039989 -0.8127365 -1.3859780        Inf
```

`N <- 1390; ro <- 0.6; a <- 0`. The last value of `(a+v[-1]) / ro^(2:N)` is representable and thus nothing changes.

```
N <- 1390; ro <- 0.6; a <- 0
set.seed(1)
v <- ts(rnorm(N,0,1))

# Formula technique
y1 <- ts(rep(0,N))  # y[1]:=0 defined
y1[-1] <- ro^(2:N) * (y1[1]/ro + cumsum((a+v[-1]) / ro^(2:N)))

tail((a+v[-1]) / ro^(2:N))
#[1]  1.049540e+307 -1.581977e+306 -3.189985e+307 -7.577105e+307            Inf
#[6] -5.546904e+307
tail(cumsum((a+v[-1]) / ro^(2:N)))
#[1] -7.648815e+306 -9.230793e+306 -4.113064e+307 -1.169017e+308            Inf
#[6]            Inf
tail(y1)
#[1] -0.4198324 -0.3039989 -0.8127365 -1.3859780        Inf        Inf
```

`N <- 1391; ro <- 0.6; a <- 0` the last value of `(a+v[-1]) / ro^(2:N)` becomes `-Inf` (smaller than `.Machine$double.xmin`) and the cumsum has to add `Inf` and `-Inf`, which gives a `NaN`, which means not a number. The `mean` of `NaN` s is not a number as well and the `sd(NaN)` is `NA`.

```
N <- 1391; ro <- 0.6; a <- 0
set.seed(1)
v <- ts(rnorm(N,0,1))

# Formula technique
y1 <- ts(rep(0,N))  # y[1]:=0 defined
y1[-1] <- ro^(2:N) * (y1[1]/ro + cumsum((a+v[-1]) / ro^(2:N)))


tail((a+v[-1]) / ro^(2:N))
#[1] -1.581977e+306 -3.189985e+307 -7.577105e+307            Inf -5.546904e+307
#[6]           -Inf
tail(cumsum((a+v[-1]) / ro^(2:N)))
#[1] -9.230793e+306 -4.113064e+307 -1.169017e+308            Inf            Inf
#[6]            NaN
tail(y1)
#[1] -0.3039989 -0.8127365 -1.3859780        Inf        Inf        NaN
```